# animated autosizing images are not visible

Tags: xcode, nib

[The images here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401848/) show the animated autosizing images available in the Size Inspector Utility. Why am I not able to see those images in my xib files or my storyboards? That part of the Size Inspector is invisible on my computer. When I am in the Size Inspector and then click on one of the other Inspector's buttons, I can see the desired image flash on the screen for an instant before the other Inspector comes into view.

Comment: there seem to be something wrong with that project. have you tried creating a new project and then plug in a image view and see if the same thing happens? if it does not happen in a new project just copy your code over to the new project. if it happens to new project also, then try re instaling your Xcode. and see if it gets rid of the issue. just a thought:)

Comment: When some applications get squirrelly, you can remove a file from Preferences and it recreates that file. Is there such a file for Xcode, and could that help?

Comment: I am not aware of such in xcode. Generally when there is a bug in a file in xcode re installing it will get rid of that. I have had to that once or twice. Did you try porting your code to a new project?